# How to customize storage path for kubernetes pods using glusterfs

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

Glusterfs create a volume and set auth.allow for all kubernetes nodes.
Then I can use kubernetes endpoint to use glusterfs volume.
But,If I create too many rc or pods using glusterfs endpoint, the data is all in the same gluster volume path / .

I know I can create create more glusterfs volume and kubernetes endpoints for each rc or pods to use. But I don't think it's the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want different data sets, you need to create different volumes.  I'm not sure what other answer you're looking for?

Comment: This is a comment. Please read the rules of this site in the [help]. You have enough rep to comment.

Comment: It is an answer - OP posited that it's not best practice.  I'm saying it's the only practice.